# Тавтология во фразе "Награжден государственной наградой"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Имеется ли тавтология в предложении: "Награжден государственной наградой — медалью «За отвагу»? Как лучше написать?

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, *награжден наградой* - как масло масляное. Можно, например, сказать: *имеет государственную награду - медаль "За отвагу"*. Или так: *награжден медалью "За отвагу"*. Вы такие варианты не рассматривали?

Answer (score 0):

Я не считаю, что в данном случае есть нежелательная тавтология. Т.е. тавтология-то есть, но не всякая тавтология - ошибка, даже стилистическая. Впрочем, варианты olsa вполне приемлемы.